# Update drop down using ajax drop down list event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5

On the aspx page I have two drop down controls:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClients" DataTextField="Client_Name"
        DataValueField="Client_Name" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" ondatabound="DropDownList3_DataBound">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddQualIDInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsQual" DataTextField="Project_Name"
        DataValueField="Qual_ID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code behind file I have code to update and rebuild the second drop down option based on the selected value from the first drop down menu:

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dsQual.Where = "Client_Name = \"" + ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue +"\"";
}
```

The drop down get's populated some times, however mostly throws the error: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Comment: Are you creating/loading any [user]controls dynamically?

Comment: Isn't the above an attempt to load it dynamically?

Comment: No. Are there any controls that are not present in the markup and created by your code based on some conditions?